# LULC changes in Google Earth Engine using Sentinel-2 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, land-cover

I'm looking to classify land changes on river islands in the Congo River using Google Earth Engine with Sentinel-2 data. I need to obtain two cloud-free images for classification and then clip my images so that it is only a certain area in my tile that I analyse. I then need to classify and train the data using supervised classification and finally do a confusion matrix. I'm not sure how to start as I'm new to GEE and JavaScript.
This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
var START_DATE = '2016-7-4';
var END_DATE = '2021-3-3';
var MGRS_TILE = '33MYU';
// Malebo pool should be '33MWR', but for some reason it only shows the top corner of the tile?

// get tile
var s2_unsorted = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', MGRS_TILE)
                    .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
                    .filterBounds(Islands);
var s2_sorted = s2_unsorted.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE');

// Convert the collection to a list and get the number of images.
var size = s2_sorted.toList(1).length();
print('Number of images: ', size);

// Get the number of images.
var count = s2_sorted.size();
print('Count: ', count);

// Get the date range of images in the collection.
var dates = ee.List(s2_sorted.get('date_range'));
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
print('Date range: ', dateRange);

// Get statistics for a property of the images in the collection.
var sunStats = s2_sorted.aggregate_stats('SUN_ELEVATION');
print('Sun elevation statistics: ', sunStats);

// Sort by a cloud cover property, get the least cloudy image.
var image = ee.Image(s2_sorted.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
print('Least cloudy image: ', image);

// Limit the collection to the 10 most recent images.
var recent = s2_sorted.sort('system:time_start', false).limit(10);
print('Recent images: ', recent);

var least_cloudy_image = ee.Image(s2_sorted.first());
//var least_cloudy_image = ee.Image(s2_sorted.mean());


// Visualization parameters 
var visParams = {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 3048, gamma: 1};
var visParams_ndvi = {min: -0.2, max: 0.8, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

//Sandy Beach area
Map.setCenter(16.86, -1.25, 15);
// Malebo pool should be below


//Map.centerObject(least_cloudy_image);
Map.addLayer(
  least_cloudy_image,
  {bands:'B4,B3,B2', min:0, max:3048, gamma: 1},
  'least cloudy image'
);    
print('least cloudy image', least_cloudy_image);

// Calculate NDVI
var image_ndvi = least_cloudy_image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
.filterBounds(Islands);

// Map results
//Map.centerObject(image,9)
Map.addLayer(least_cloudy_image,visParams,'Sentinel-2 False Color Infrared')
Map.addLayer(image_ndvi,visParams_ndvi,'Sentinel-2 NDVI')

var newfc = Forest1.merge(Agriculture1).merge(Burnt1);
print(newfc);

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','B8'];

var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training);

var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(training.first().propertyNames())
);

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});

var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);

Map.centerObject(newfc, 11);
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['green', 'blue', 'red']},
'classification');
Map.addLayer(newfc);
```